# TypeScript interface method implementation in a class

Tags: typescript, oop

So I have this weird observation and would like some clarity on this, I have made a few interfaces that I have implemented with different classes and I found the following:

When I had implemented a method that is part of the TaxableLineItem Interface into this class Revenue, I was able to change the parameters when implementing the interface's method(applyTax), i.e. the parameter type to (input :TaxRate) instead of the specified (input: Input)

```
interface LineItem {
  getAmount(): number;
  getType(): ELineItemType;
  applyForecast(input?: Input, prevCFLineItem?: LineItem): void;
}
interface TaxableLineItem{
  applyTax(input: Input): void;
  getPostTaxAmount(): number;
}

class Revenue implements LineItem, TaxableLineItem{
    private amount: number;
    private postTaxAmount: number;
    private type: ELineItemType;
    
    /**other implemented methods and constructor*/

    applyTax(input: TaxRate): void {
      this.postTaxAmount = this.amount * input.getResidualMargin();
   }
      
}
```

I feel like this was doable because I had implemented the Input interface in the TaxRate class as such:

```
interface Input {
  getVariableAmount(): number;
}

class TaxRate implements Input, IMargin {
  private taxRate: number;
  constructor(taxRate: number) {
    this.taxRate = taxRate;
  }
  getResidualMargin(): number {
    return 1 - this.taxRate;
  }
  getVariableAmount(): number {
    return this.taxRate;
  }
}
```

My guess is that because TaxRate implements Input , the ts compiler accepts that revenue implementation applyTax method

Is there any other explanation for this?

Comment: This is normal and exactly what you'd expect. As you say, `TaxRate` implements `Input` and therefore has every property and method that `Input` has. You can always pass a more specific implementation of interface `A` to a function that expects interface `A` as a parameter.